# how to do this in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to have a structure such as this on an MVC razor view:

```
 if(model.x!=null)
 {
     <div> 
      someComplexView
  }
  someOtherComplexView
  if(model.x!=null)
 {
     </div> 
 }
```

But it doesn't work as the  **div** is not inside one if block. How can I do it without using partialView?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<text>` to wrap your div parts.

```
<text><div></text>
```

...

```
<text></div></text>
```

See also [Why does Razor not like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040482/why-does-razor-not-like-this)

You could also review your reasons for using the `<div>` wrapper. Would it be enough to just change the class of the div wrapper when `model.x != null`, and use that to style the results?

Comment: Not working :( I am getting this error:  Encountered end tag "text" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Comment: yes I did, the result is very similar to e2burner, but I am getting error on this section. Seems that the first section is ok.

Comment: I want to have a tab when x is not null, but no tab (only second view) when x is null. Any solution? ( ia m suing JQuery for tab control)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @if(model.x!=null)
 {
    <text> <div> </text> 
      someComplexView
 }
  someOtherComplexView
 @if(model.x!=null)
 {
     <text></div></text> 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What the purpose of your code ? Looks logically wrong, you got twice the same  `if(model.x!=null)`, what are you trying to do ?
It should be more something like :

```
 if(model.x!=null)
 {
     <div> 
      someComplexView
     </div> 
 }
 someOtherComplexView
```

Comment: I wangt to have a div around both complex views, when X is not null, but when X is null, only one view shows and no div around it.

Comment: ya, why not use the `else` block ?

Comment: Define complex views please. You're repeating twice if(model.x!=null), and the question is unclear.. Have a look on how to build views using razor: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvc3razor.aspx

Comment: By complex view, I mean a view that I want to write it twice, if the views were simple, the simplest way to solev the problem was to use if the else and repeat them inside if and else sections.

Answer (score 0):

from what you say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350001/how-to-do-this-in-razor-view#comment16582458_12350103)

> I want to have a div around both complex views, when X is not null, but when X is null, only one view shows and no div around it.

you can do this

```
if(model.x!=null)
 {
     <div> 
      someComplexView
     someOtherComplexView
     </div> 
 }
 else
 {
    someOtherComplexView
 }
```

so in this way, only when your model.x is NOT null a div will be used else no divs.

Comment: This is not correct. When X is not null, I have only one view inside a div. But I want to have both view inside a div.

Comment: No, Since I need to write SomeotherComplexView twice. I can do this using partialview, but the question is not using partial view